# layout_marginBottom not working when using match_parent or wrap_content under relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am writing this layout code for my listview.
Below is d code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/thumb"
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/title"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/desc"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:text="@string/desc"
android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/arrow"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the parent element of RelativeLayout the first child element ImageView is where the problem resides, in which all the layout margin properties except layout_marginBottom is working.
What could be the problem, if someone can figure it out

**Desired Image**

[image: Desired Image]

**What I have right now**

[image: What I have right now]

Comment: padding is working...what u really want pls tel?

Comment: no padding is not working

Comment: in my end its working..pls post ur desired and current image pls..

Comment: how to post image in stack overflow.. sorry i am new so dont know

Comment: @user3928711 [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks kaushik..it matched exactly to the answer i have written below.

Comment: glad it helped happy coding 
:)

Answer (score 2):

try this..change ur imageview like this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"
        android:text="titleDsdsadasds"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:text="descsdfsdfdfsdf"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Drone dev ... can u specify how to do it

Answer (score 1):

well i can see that you have not given any margin bottom to your imageview.Correct me if i'm wrong but i guess you want `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"` instead of `android:paddingBottom="10dp"`.So you may want to replace it like below-

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/thumb"
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

padding is to give spacing from inside of the view and margin for outside.

Comment: i have tried it too. somewhere i read about giving padding solves d issue so tried it. but does not. any other solution?

Comment: @user3928711 well you can post a pic of your layout so that i can understand your prob

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="15dp"
android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumb"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumb"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ddd"

        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="AAAAAA"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="AAAAAAAAAAA"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: I found out the solution.. u have to remove all d padding attributes from the imageview and add it to the relative layout containing it